# Validação de width e height máximo com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo upload de uma imagem diretamente para uma database mas quero verificar o seu width e height e se não estiver entre (X,X) de width e (X,X) de height não insere os dados na base de dados e mostra uma mensagem de erro a dizer que as medidas da foto não são válidas!

Qualquer informação que achem importante por favor pedir! Espero ter me explicado corretamente.

**Meu código**

```
 if (isset($_POST['publicar'])) {
   $nomemembro = $_POST['nomemembro'];
 $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];

 $name = $_FILES['imgmembro']['name'];
 $target_file = basename($_FILES["imgmembro"]["name"]);

     // Select file type
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

     // Valid file extensions
    $extensions_arr = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

   // Check extension
    if (in_array($imageFileType, $extensions_arr)) {

    // Convert to base64 
    $image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['imgmembro'] 
 ['tmp_name']));
    $image = 'data:image/' . $imageFileType . ';base64,' . $image_base64;


    $query = "INSERT INTO equipa(nomeprof, foto, cargo) VALUES 
  ('$nomemembro','" . $image . "' ,'$cargo')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Membro da equipa adicionado com sucesso!")';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Insira um formato de imagem válida!")';
    echo '</script>';
}
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pode usar [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getimagesize.php) :

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("img/flag.jpg");
echo "<img src=\"img/flag.jpg\" $attr alt=\"getimagesize() example\" />";
```

tente assim :

```
if (isset($_POST['publicar'])) {
   $nomemembro = $_POST['nomemembro'];
 $cargo = $_POST['cargo'];

 $name = $_FILES['imgmembro']['name'];
 $target_file = basename($_FILES["imgmembro"]["name"]);

     // Select file type
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

     // Valid file extensions
    $extensions_arr = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");

   // Check extension
    if (in_array($imageFileType, $extensions_arr)) {

    $img = $_FILES['imgmembro'] ['tmp_name'];
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($img);


    echo 'SIZE : '.$width.'x'.$height;

    // Convert to base64 
    $image_base64 = base64_encode($img);
    $image = 'data:image/' . $imageFileType . ';base64,' . $image_base64;


    $query = "INSERT INTO equipa(nomeprof, foto, cargo) VALUES 
  ('$nomemembro','" . $image . "' ,'$cargo')";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Membro da equipa adicionado com sucesso!")';
    echo '</script>';
} else {
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert("Insira um formato de imagem válida!")';
    echo '</script>';
}
      }
```

Comment: Nesse exemplo está verificando uma imagem e eu quero verificar uma imagem que vêm dum POST é possível?

Comment: uma imagem e uma imagem, que ela seja do POST o não e a mesma coisa, não faz nenhuma diferençia !

Comment: Não estou conseguindo tirar o valor de height e width!!

Comment: Ver meu EDIT !!!